org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error registering Avro schema
https://i.sstatic.net/jtpBxVPF.png
I send a message from procuder to kafkaya and consumer listens to it.but i can't save the schema in shema registry
2024-07-26T10:22:03.461+03:00  INFO 19888 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer     : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Instantiated an idempotent producer.
2024-07-26T10:22:03.486+03:00  INFO 19888 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 3.6.0
2024-07-26T10:22:03.486+03:00  INFO 19888 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: 60e845626d8a465a
2024-07-26T10:22:03.486+03:00  INFO 19888 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1721978523486
2024-07-26T10:22:03.500+03:00  INFO 19888 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Cluster ID: GMSwwr81QViyTcsJvLQfJw
2024-07-26T10:22:03.501+03:00  INFO 19888 --- [ad | producer-1] o.a.k.c.p.internals.TransactionManager   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] ProducerId set to 4 with epoch 0
2024-07-26T10:22:03.607+03:00 ERROR 19888 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error registering Avro schema{"type":"record","name":"Student","namespace":"com.prepwork.kreadwritemsg.kafka.avro.model","fields":[{"name":"studentName","type":"string"},{"name":"studentId","type":"string"},{"name":"age","type":"int"}]}] with root cause

io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: 404 Not Found; error code: 50005
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:333) ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-7.4.1.jar:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:406) ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-7.4.1.jar:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:586) ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-7.4.1.jar:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:574) ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-7.4.1.jar:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.registerAndGetId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:311) ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-7.4.1.jar:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.registerWithResponse(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:427) ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-7.4.1.jar:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.registerWithResponse(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:404) ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-7.4.1.jar:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.registerWithResponse(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.java:506) ~[kafka-schema-serializer-7.4.1.jar:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:118) ~[kafka-avro-serializer-7.4.1.jar:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.serialize(KafkaAvroSerializer.java:67) ~[kafka-avro-serializer-7.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:1000) ~[kafka-clients-3.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:947) ~[kafka-clients-3.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory$CloseSafeProducer.send(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:1050) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.doSend(KafkaTemplate.java:787) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.observeSend(KafkaTemplate.java:756) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTemplate.java:545) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at com.services.kafkaAvroProdCons.producer.KfkaProducerService.sendAvroData(KfkaProducerService.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.services.kafkaAvroProdCons.controller.KfkaProducerController.getDataForKafkaTopic(KfkaProducerController.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:254) ~[spring-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:182) ~[spring-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:917) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:829) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1570) ~[na:na]


Did you check what error code: 50005 means? If it is possible to create a [mcve] then I suggest that you [edit] your question and post one.
